# Creating a default

Tags: python-3.x

I have a point class which has 2-d point instances. I also have a magnitude function inside which returns the magnitude of said points. Below is my code...

```
class Point:
#    """2-D Point objects."""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
    #       """Initialize the Point instance"""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_magnitude(self):
    #       """Return the magnitude of vector from (0,0) to self."""
        return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Point at ({}, {})'.format(self.x,self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(x={},y={})".format(self.x,self.y)
point = Point(x=3, y=4)
print(str(point))
print(repr(point))
print(point)
```

...After doing all of this, the final part of this is to implement a default point of (0,0). Any suggestions on how to do this? It should work like this...

```
    point2 = Point()
    print(point2)
Point(x=0, y=0)
    point3 = Point(y=9)
    print(point3)
Point(x=0, y=9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in [default arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) to an initializer, just like you would any other function.

```
def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
#       """Initialize the Point instance"""
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```